# jquery slide in menu animation bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a script to have a slide in top bar (branding) and a menu that site above and below a slider (or banner). When they scroll back in it's just the branding and the menu.. no slider or banner.

It works but there is a bug I can't seem to fix.

The page has 4 main elements but the SLIDER OR BANNER are option elements (not always present):

```
<div id="branding">BRANDING</div>
<div id="header">
    <div id="slider">SLIDER OR BANNER</div>
    <div id="menu">MENU</div>
</div>
<div id="content">CONTENT</div>
```

And here is my script so far:

```
     var sticky_navigation = function () {

         $lH = ($('#branding').length) ? $('#branding').height() : 0,
         $sH = ($('#slider').length) ? $('#slider').height() : 0,
         $bH = ($('#banner').length) ? $('#banner').height() : 0,
         $mH = ($('#menu').length) ? $('#menu').height() : 0;

         var $content = $('#content'), // Main content area
             $branding = $('#branding'),
             $header = $('#header'),
             $menu = $('#menu');

         // HEADER
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > $lH) {
             $header.css({
                 marginTop: $lH + "px"
             });
             if ($branding.css('position').toString() != "fixed") {
                 $branding.css({
                     position: "fixed",
                     top: "-" + $lH + "px",
                     left: 0,
                     zIndex: 500,
                 }).animate({
                     top: 0
                 }, 700);
             }
         } else {
             $branding.css({
                 position: "relative",
                 marginTop: "0px",
             });
             $header.css({
                 marginTop: "0px"
             });
         }

         // MENU
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($bH + $sH + $mH)) {
             $branding.css({
                 boxShadow: "none",
             });
             $header.css({
                 marginTop: ($lH + $mH) + "px"
             });
             if ($menu.css('position').toString() != "fixed") {
                 $menu.css({
                     position: "fixed",
                     top: "-" + $lH + "px",
                     left: 0,
                     zIndex: 490,
                 }).animate({
                     top: $lH
                 }, 700);
             }
         } else {
             $menu.css({
                 position: "relative",
                 marginTop: "0px",
                 top: 0,
             });
             if ($('#branding').length || $('#slider').length) {
                 $branding.css({
                     boxShadow: "0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
                 })
             }
         }
     };
     // run our function on load
     sticky_navigation();

     // and run it again every time you scroll
     $(window).scroll(function () {
         sticky_navigation();
     });

     // and run it again every time you resize
     $(window).resize(function () {
         sticky_navigation();
     });
```

Here is a jsfiddle for it as I have it now... to see the bug scroll up and down quickly.. you should see the menu sits lower than it should.

http://jsfiddle.net/hC423/1/

[image]

Any help with this is very much appreciated. I'm open to suggestions if there's a better way to do this.

C

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hC423/2/

Added 250ms delay after user scrolls.

if (!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

```
 var sticky_navigation = function () {

     setTimeout(function // ###### ADDED ######

     $lH = ($('#branding').length) ? $('#branding').height() : 0,
     $sH = ($('#slider').length) ? $('#slider').height() : 0,
     $bH = ($('#banner').length) ? $('#banner').height() : 0,
     $mH = ($('#menu').length) ? $('#menu').height() : 0;

     var $content = $('#content'), // Main content area
         $branding = $('#branding'),
         $header = $('#header'),
         $menu = $('#menu');

     // HEADER
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > $lH) {
         $header.css({
             marginTop: $lH + "px"
         });
         if ($branding.css('position').toString() != "fixed") {
             $branding.css({
                 position: "fixed",
                 top: "-" + $lH + "px",
                 left: 0,
                 zIndex: 500,
             }).animate({
                 top: 0
             }, 700);
         }
     } else {
         $branding.css({
             position: "relative",
             marginTop: "0px",
         });
         $header.css({
             marginTop: "0px"
         });
     }

     // MENU
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($bH + $sH + $mH)) {
         $branding.css({
             boxShadow: "none",
         });
         $header.css({
             marginTop: ($lH + $mH) + "px"
         });
         if ($menu.css('position').toString() != "fixed") {
             $menu.css({
                 position: "fixed",
                 top: "-" + $lH + "px",
                 left: 0,
                 zIndex: 490,
             }).animate({
                 top: $lH
             }, 700);
         }
     } else {
         $menu.css({
             position: "relative",
             marginTop: "0px",
             top: 0,
         });
         if ($('#branding').length || $('#slider').length) {
             $branding.css({
                 boxShadow: "0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
             })
         }
     }
   } ,250); // ###### ADDED ######
 };
 // run our function on load
 sticky_navigation();

 // and run it again every time you scroll
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     sticky_navigation();
 });

 // and run it again every time you resize
 $(window).resize(function () {
     sticky_navigation();
 });
```

};

Comment: Thanks @BlueUnicorn but the issue remains. If you scroll up then down quickly the menu still sits lower than it should... please see image attached above. Any other ideas how to fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: Try increasing the timeout from 250 and 500 and it should work. I tried with the 250 timeout and it was working for me. You are one quick scroller! :)